# Fortify JavaScript Hijacking: Vulnerable Framework aspx using Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, .net, xss, fortify, session-hijacking

I am working on a legacy system, we just scanned it with HP Fortify and got 
JavaScript Hijacking: Vulnerable Framework, the code is below.
What Can I do to secure this? I am not entirely understanding the issue.

```
function getMissionOverwriteDocsDataCountComponent(siteNo, fcg, catCode, facNo, assetUid, compNo) {
    // Make the Ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'MissionOverwriteAj.aspx',
        data: {
                reqType: 'getMissionOverwriteDocsCountComponent',
                siteNo: siteNo,
                fcg: fcg,
                catCode: catCode,
                facNo: facNo,
                assetUid: assetUid,
                compNo: compNo
            },
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        error: errorFunc,
        success: function(response){
            //alert(response);
            attCount = response;
        }
    });
}
```

This calls an ASPX page in VB

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Dim reqType As String = Request.Params("reqType")

            userID = Session(UserID).ToString()
            orgID = Session(OrgID).ToString()

            facility = New Facility(Request.Params("siteNo"), 
                                    Request.Params("facNo"), 
                                    Request.Params("fcg"), 
                                    Request.Params("catCode"), 
                                    Request.Params("assetUid"))

            ' Determine what type of call is being made.
            Select Case reqType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just kinda going on a gamble here. I think it might be referring to jQuery, but that section of your code comes up since it contains jQuery.

[This site](https://snyk.io/vuln/npm:jquery?lh@2.1.4) shows that Jquery has some issues in earlier versions. Try updating jQuery and rerun your audit. That should hopefully resolve the issue.

Comment: I think you might be right I just looked and it have several version of jquery 1.x from 1.4.2 to 1.10.3